# Script for File upload in google drive - Error encountered: An unexpected error occurred

Tags: file-upload, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use a script to upload document into google spreadsheet and automatically put link to it into current cell. Since yesterday all was gone fine, but since this morning i receive this generic error:
https://docs.google.com
Error encountered: An unexpected error occurred

This is the code:

```
// upload document into google spreadsheet
// and put link to it into current cell

function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "Accedi al modulo per allegare un file...", functionName: "doGet"});
  ss.addMenu("Carica scheda di rilevazione dati...", menuEntries);
}

function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("FORM per il caricamento della scheda di rilevazione dati");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
  var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
  var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
  form.add(formContent);  
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));

  // these parameters need to be passed by form
  // in doPost() these cannot be found out anymore
  formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeCell", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()));
  formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeSheet", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()));
  formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeSpreadsheet", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()));
  formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton('Invia ed archivia scheda'));
  app.add(form);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
  return app;
}

function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.createLabel('sto salvando...');
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
  var doc = DocsList.getFolderById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').createFile(fileBlob);
  var label = app.createLabel('file caricato con successo');

  // write value into current cell
  var value = 'hyperlink("' + doc.getUrl() + '";"' + doc.getName() + '")'
  var activeSpreadsheet = e.parameter.activeSpreadsheet;
  var activeSheet = e.parameter.activeSheet;
  var activeCell = e.parameter.activeCell;
  var label = app.createLabel('file memorizzato correttamente');
  app.add(label);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(activeSpreadsheet).getSheetByName(activeSheet).getRange(activeCell).setFormula(value);
  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the UiApp Service has been deprecated. Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/54605042/1595451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According to Your Question**

Since yesterday  all was gone fine, but since this morning i receive this generic error: https://docs.google.com Error encountered: An unexpected error occurred

**According to Google developers** [page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/)

[image]

So, I think problem may be in

> var doc = DocsList.getFolderById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').createFile(fileBlob);

try to use **DriveApp** instead of **DocList**. [more info](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFolderById(String))

Comment: ...fast and effective! Your intuition is perfect and my problem solved. Thanks for the fantastic support!